# What the browser assumes the "#" literal in URL as?

Tags: url

I want to pass a querystring in the URL which has value of "fd123+#12" where I am taking "+" and "#"as literal and they are not the encoded value. Due to business requirement, I can't use "fd123%20%2312". So I guess the only solution I have to get rid of the characters "+" and "#" from querystring parameter.I know the browser assumes "+" in URL querystring as space, could someone please tell me what the browser assumes the literal "#" as in the URL? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of research I found the answer for my question - Browser will assume "#" pound in URLs to indicate where a fragment identifier i.e. bookmarks/anchors in HTML begins.